# How to select from a list of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table with Users with Id and UserName
But I know that not all existing users have been added.
I have a list of all those ids (1,9,12,22,109)(the list is very long)
I want to find which id I don't have in my database
EXCEPT requires a SELECT, and I couldn't figure out how to select from a list.

Comment: Split the string (into rows) and use a `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).